# Struts2 WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property

Tags: struts2, warnings, ognl

My struts2 application works fine, I just keep getting these warnings for properties I may or may not need.  Any advice on how to get rid of the warnings?

```
10:17:17,184  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [org.apache.catalina.jsp_file]
10:17:17,278  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [templateDir]
10:17:17,294  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [theme]
10:17:17,387  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [.freemarker.Request]
10:17:17,387  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [.freemarker.RequestParameters]
10:17:17,637  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [select.tin]
10:17:17,762  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [text]
10:17:17,778  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [select.year]
10:17:17,778  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [year]
10:17:17,981  WARN OgnlValueStack:45 - Could not find property [struts.actionMapping]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Report at JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3067?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs)

**Solution** : See the [Missing Properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/S2WIKI/troubleshooting-guide-migrating-from-struts-20x-to-21x.html#TroubleshootingguidemigratingfromStruts2.0.xto2.1.x-MissingProperties) section in *Troubleshooting guide migrating from Struts 2.0.x to 2.1.x*